# Jasper Report html output Image shows cached image in IE and Firefox but works all fine in Chrome

Tags: jasper-reports, portlet, jsf-1.2

I have produced a jasper report in my application (JSF1.2,RichFaces 3.3.3,Portlet bridge), but I am facing a problem. The image produced by jasper is not changing dynamically even by rerendering its area. After a lot of discussions and analysis I have concluded that because the jasper provides image(new and old) with the same name... Hence the browser is not loading this image again and getting this image from the cache. I have also added the following code in the head section of the xhtml(portlet), but the result is still not changed.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
```

Please let me know if someone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with image caching with Jasper 
Here is the code

Just pass the random value along with image params

> exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,
>                 "image?random="+Math.random()+"&image=");

Answer (score 0):

if the whole report is an image you can tray this hack

```
<img src="/yourpath/imagename.png?{put_current_time_here or some random string}" />
```

Comment: As I didnot find any answer from this forum, I have found a workarround for this problem. i.e. I have reloaded the page and now the problem is resolved. Thanks!